# Use Python standard logging in Celery

Tags: python, django, logging, standards, celery

I have to implement Celery in a pre-existing system. The previous version of the system already used Python standard logging.

My code is similar to the code below. Process one and process two are non-Celery functions, which are logging everywhere. We are using the logging to track data loss if something bad happens.

```
@task
def add(x,y):
    process_one(x,y)
    process_two(x,y)
```

How can I implement Celery and use the Python standard logging instead Celery logging, so our old logging system is not lost?

I have tried to change `import logging` from Python to: `logger = add.get_logger()` and pass the `logger` to all functions, but I don't think it is a good practice. I need another solution.

**Update: to add application logging in Celery logging, you can perform:**

```
$ manage.py celeryd -v 2 -B -s celery -E -l debug --traceback \
  --settings=settings --logfile=/(path to your log folder)/celeryd.log
```

With `-l` (logging) as `debug`, our application/Python logging is automatically included in our Celery logging: No need to perform `logger = add.get_logger()`.

Answer (score 17):

You probably want this setting:

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False
```

Tell me how that works out.

Btw, the reason it hijacks the root logger is because some badly written
libraries sets up logging, something a library should never do, resulting in users experiencing no output from the celeryd
worker :(

Comment: Hi Asksol, thank you for your answer. Ya I'm agree with you about the bad library thing. I already tried the CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER thing. When I consult to my friend, he told me that is not wise to make CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False because celeryd worker logging is very important and more powerful. The output is, celery only redirect the log responsibility from celery logger to root/python logger and the result is the same. I think if it happen like that, I prefer for using celery logger instead the python one.

Comment: So the celery library sets up logging because badly written libraries set up logging? ;) Sounds like a 'you look like trouble, so I better shoot you first' argument.

Comment: @hheimbuerger: Hehe, nice. But it's not really accurate to think of Celery as a library. Celery is a distributed task queue *app* and you essentially just configure it (in the form of code) with specifics to accomplish what you want. Admittedly, this can become quite a bit muddier when integrating with *other apps* like Django.

Comment: @Manganeez How is that relevant to its logging?

Comment: @hheimbuerger Sorry, the relevance seems clear to me, but I'll restate. You criticized celery as being a library that contradicts the author's statement that libraries shouldn't set up logging. I pointed out that celery is not a library - it's an *app*, so the author's statement about logging doesn't apply to it.

Comment: @Manganeez Well, in this case, I change my statement to: "So celery sets up logging because other badly written software sets up logging."
My point still stands: celery implicitly criticises that other software tampers with the logging setup. My problem is that celery tampers with my logging setup. I find this ironic. Whether you call it a library or an app.

Comment: @hheimbuerger So your position is that software shouldn't log? If you install an app like, say, Apache, you expect it to *not* have a default logging configuration? *All* software logging is by definition set up by software. I suspect you've misspoken again, but it's not worth an argument. We disagree.

Comment: I'm in this pit right now. I have my django app configured to log in specific ways, and i would really love if celery would just use the configured loggers instead of 'doing it's own thing' which as I understand it, is what's happening. By the way, I don't think Henrik said anywhere, that software shouldn't log, he specifically says that it should tamper with his logging setup', which I completely agree with.