# Celery Logging: consistent way to log inside and outside of a task

Tags: python, django, logging, task, celery

I'm running a Celery task that executes a function.  This function generates some logging information.  Using the get_task_logger logger, I am able print the logging information to the Celery stdout.

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

def my_func_called_inside_a_task():
    logger.debug("SOME OUTPUT HERE")
```

However, I also want to import this function as a normal python script (not using Celery) and log to, for example, stdout. Normally, I might do something like the following:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_func_called_inside_a_task():
    logger.debug("SOME OUTPUT HERE")
```

How do I combine both approaches so I don't have to do something redundant like the following?

```
import logging
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger_celery = get_task_logger(__name__)

def my_func_called_inside_a_task():
    logger.debug("SOME OUTPUT HERE")
    logger_celery.debug("SOME OUTPUT HERE")
```

Summary: 
If I call the function from a celery task, I'd like it to log to the celery worker stdout.  If I call the function from a normal Python prompt, it would use the normal Python logger.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Python standard logging in Celery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940987/use-python-standard-logging-in-celery)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass an optional argument to that function.

```
import logging
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger


def my_func_called_inside_a_task(use_celery_logger=None):
    if use_celery_logger:
        logger = get_task_logger(__name__)
    else:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    logger.debug("SOME OUTPUT HERE")
```

and in Your celery task call it as

```
my_func_called_inside_a_task(use_celery_logger=True)
```

and for normal logging you can call it as it is

```
my_func_called_inside_a_task()
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up using a variation of this approach.

Comment: I think  `use_celery_logger` would be a better name for that boolean kwarg, `celery_callback` sounds like you should pass a function.

Comment: @Anentropic Makes sense. Updated. Thanks.